# How can I type in a textbox and have whatever I typed simultaneously appear in a div?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I want to have it so when I type into a textbox (or an input field) and have whatever I am typing simultaneously appear in a div or just other place on the page?

The stackoverflow site does this when we type up a question. As we type a question, it shows whatever we are typing in a box below the textbox.
Hope my question makes sense!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you all. Stackoverflow (the community in particular) and jQuery are the greatest thing since the start of the internet. Again thanks for the help. Maybe one day I can return the favor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The StackOverflow site does a bit more because it does syntax highlighting too, but the basic idea is to listen to the keyboard events - `keydown` (better), `keypress` or `keyup` (not so good if a button is continuously pressed) and in its callback update the value of the target container with the value of the source container. Here's a quick example.

The best solution is to bind to both - `keyup` and (`keydown` or `keypress`). Reason being when the `key(press|down)` callbacks are fired, the value of the textbox is still the old value so when when we update the target container, it doesn't get the last character. `keyup` on the other hand is fired after the value of the text box is updated. However, `keyup` will not fire if you keep a button pressed as the button is only released once, so the target updates at the very end. The solution is to use both :)

```
$("textarea").bind('keyup keydown', function() {
    $("#target").html(this.val());
});
```

See an [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/TJgFe/2).

Comment: keydown will not repeat the last character.

Comment: Good point @Gert. Maybe `keyup` is better but the problem of continuous button press still remains. Needs a better approach to solve both issues. The SO answer preview solves it quite well :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`.keydown()`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) function to achieve this effect:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#foo').keydown(function() {
            $('#result').text($(this).val());
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="foo" id="foo" />
    <div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Good question... never thought of it before, but that functionality is cool.

I went to View Source:

There's a function attached to this page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() { 
        editorReady(1, heartbeat.answers);
    });   
</script>
```

The URL here contains the function "editorReady".
    http://sstatic.net/js/question.js?v=b05e8725a843